# Setting default build directory in QtCreator to use lowercase CurrentBuild:Name

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to set the default build directory in qtCreator to, depending on build type:

```
bin/debug
bin/release
```

I have changed the default value of

```
../build-%{CurrentProject:Name}-%{CurrentKit:FileSystemName}-%{CurrentBuild:Name}
```

to

```
bin/%{CurrentBuild:Name}
```

It builds fine, creates the directories etc; only issue is it creates the `Debug|Release` directory with a capital letter. Is there a way to make this lower case as every other folder in the path is lower case?

Comment: http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Undocumented_qmake may be helpful.  `lower(string) — Converts the string to lower case.`

Comment: the comment above probably won't help.  I tried it in the default build dir dialog in the options and no luck.  The other option that might help, is to use shadow building, and just let it make the default release and debug folders that gets included.  Those are lowercase by default.

Comment: @phyatt - as you say using lower() doesn't work. I'm trying to set the value found in: tools > options > build & run > general > default build directory. So when I create a new project/open an existing one for the first time, the debug and release folders locations are automatically set. Have looked into shadow builds but think that is more a post set up activity I'd have to do on each project? Unless you know of a way to automatically set them?

Answer (score 2):

While I have been unable to find a way to make arbitrary strings lowercase, there is a variable that has the lowercase build type: 'CurrentBuild:Type'

So, the following default build path accomplishes what you want:

./bin/%{CurrentBuild:Type}